# How to view methods return value in PyCharm 2016.1

Tags: pycharm

If I put a breakpoint on the last line of the return statement, it just skips it. I am aware that there should be a "Show Method Return Values" option when I click the debug cogwheel, but there isn't.

Any alternatives?

```
return render(request, get_template(request, "users.html"), {
    'base_toolbar_section': 'users',
    'base_user': base_user(request.user),
    'get_profile': get_profile(request.user),
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Show returned value" feature is available in current EAP builds and will be available in 2016.2 version.

Comment: Huh. Can't wait! Thanks.